# nginx forward request with the same domain

Tags: nginx

I'm not an expert on networking or servers but I need to configure Nginx server, this  server will listen two different external addresses:

1. https://fake.net
2. https://example.com

I have a Node.js application locally in this server deployed in: http://localhost:3020

I'm trying to proxy from nginx to the Node.js app but, the thing is that I need the Node.js api to received the request with the original url request.

Is there any way to forward the request in this way:

Request: https://fake.net/api/test -------> In the Node app received: http://fake.net/api/test

Request: https://example.com/api/test1 -------> In the Node app received: http://example.net/api/test1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Host` header defines the domain part of the proxied request. Generally `$host` is used to get the value from the original request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) for details.

The request is passed transparently if no optional URI is provided to the `proxy_pass` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3020;
}
```